# can someone explain how i can pull specific fields from a dict in python

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I'm using python 2.7 and the ebay sdk v2

I have a dict stored and Im writing it to a csv file(trying), problem is i only want certain fields i dont want to have to write out every column

here is my dict

```
{'itemSearchURL': 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?LH_ItemCondition=1&_nkw=OMP+OD%2F1989&_ddo=1&_ipg=1&_pgn=1', 'paginationOutput': {'totalPages': '187', 'entriesPerPage': '1', 'pageNumber': '1', 'totalEntries': '187'}, 'ack': 'Success', 'timestamp': '2016-11-15T15:52:01.356Z', 'searchResult': {'item': [{'itemId': '322324027874', 'subtitle': '100% GENUINE OMP STEERING WHEEL - NOT A CHEAP FAKE COPY', 'globalId': 'EBAY-GB', 'title': 'OD/1989/NN OMP TRECENTO UNO SPORTS STEERING WHEEL 300mm in BLACK POLYURETHANE', 'country': 'GB', 'primaryCategory': {'categoryId': '40195', 'categoryName': 'Steering Wheels & Boss Kits'}, 'autoPay': 'false', 'galleryURL': 'http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/miOhEO1pDb2cff4pPcZpwIQ/140.jpg', 'shippingInfo': {'shippingType': 'Free', 'shipToLocations': ['AU', 'Americas', 'Europe', 'Asia'], 'shippingServiceCost': {'_currencyId': 'GBP', 'value': '0.0'}}, 'location': 'United Kingdom', 'topRatedListing': 'false', 'viewItemURL': 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/OD-1989-NN-OMP-TRECENTO-UNO-SPORTS-STEERING-WHEEL-300mm-BLACK-POLYURETHANE-/322324027874', 'sellingStatus': {'currentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'GBP', 'value': '78.28'}, 'timeLeft': 'P25DT0H21M7S', 'convertedCurrentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'GBP', 'value': '78.28'}, 'sellingState': 'Active'}, 'paymentMethod': 'PayPal', 'isMultiVariationListing': 'false', 'condition': {'conditionId': '1000', 'conditionDisplayName': 'New'}, 'listingInfo': {'listingType': 'FixedPrice', 'gift': 'false', 'bestOfferEnabled': 'false', 'startTime': '2016-11-10T16:13:08.000Z', 'buyItNowAvailable': 'false', 'endTime': '2016-12-10T16:13:08.000Z'}}], '_count': '1'}, 'version': '1.13.0'}
```

here is my section of code thats not working

```
def WriteDictToCSV(csv_file,csv_columns,dict_data):
    try:
        with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in dict_data:
                writer.writerow(data)
    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
            print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror))    
    return            

csv_columns = ['itemId','title','subtitle','viewItemURL']


currentPath = os.getcwd()
csv_file = currentPath + "/csv/items.csv"

WriteDictToCSV(csv_file,csv_columns,response.dict())
```

this is my error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/richard/workspace/ebay title search by csv/learning2.py", line 56, in <module>
        WriteDictToCSV(csv_file,csv_columns,response.dict())
      File "/home/richard/workspace/ebay title search by csv/learning2.py", line 45, in WriteDictToCSV
        writer.writerow(data)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in writerow
        return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/csv.py", line 144, in _dict_to_list
        ", ".join(wrong_fields))
    ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: i, t, e, m, S, e, a, r, c, h, U, R, L
```

I understand that i'm missing the column names but really dont know how to parse the bits i want out of the dict i was thinkink about converting the dict to xml and using etree as seen some guides on the net of how to do that but really would like to learn how to work with the dict as it is

I also tried with a for loop but that just gave me errors saying no value

```
for item in response.dict()['searchResult']['item']:
    print "ItemID: %s" % item['itemId'].value
    print "Title: %s" % item['title'].value
    print "CategoryID: %s" % item['primaryCategory']['categoryId'].value
```

I'm struggling to get my head around the container

if i do a for loop through the dict i can see the keys and values.

```
mydata = response.dict()  
for key, value in mydata.items():
    print key, value
```

that give me an output in keys

I was thinking of enumerating them and extracting a single key but read that dictionaries are not ordered so it would come out with different results is this true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the *single dictionary* you passed in:

```
for data in dict_data:
    writer.writerow(data)
```

This passes in each *key* from the dictionary as a separate row; each row is supposed to be a dictionary and the `csv` module uses iteration over the row to test for extra keys. This is why you see each individual letter from the first key (`itemSearchURL` here).

Pass in that *list* of dictionaries buried under the `['searchResult']['item']` keys:

```
WriteDictToCSV(csv_file, csv_columns, response.dict()['searchResult']['item'])
```

Now `dict_data` is a sequence of `dict` objects, `data` will be one of the dictionaries in the list.

Next, these dictionaries contain *more keys* than what you told the `DictWriter` instance about, so you'll still get an error:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'globalId', 'country', 'primaryCategory', 'autoPay', 'galleryURL', 'shippingInfo', 'location', 'topRatedListing', 'sellingStatus', 'paymentMethod', 'isMultiVariationListing', 'condition', 'listingInfo'
```

Tell `DictWriter` to ignore these with `extrasaction='ignore'`:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=csv_columns, extrasaction='ignore')
```

Last but not least, you don't have to do any of that looping yourself; just use `writer.writerows()` (plural, note the `s` at the end) to write a list of rows in one go:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=csv_columns, extrasaction='ignore')
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(dict_data)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> response_dict = {'itemSearchURL': 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?LH_ItemCondition=1&_nkw=OMP+OD%2F1989&_ddo=1&_ipg=1&_pgn=1', 'paginationOutput': {'totalPages': '187', 'entriesPerPage': '1', 'pageNumber': '1', 'totalEntries': '187'}, 'ack': 'Success', 'timestamp': '2016-11-15T15:52:01.356Z', 'searchResult': {'item': [{'itemId': '322324027874', 'subtitle': '100% GENUINE OMP STEERING WHEEL - NOT A CHEAP FAKE COPY', 'globalId': 'EBAY-GB', 'title': 'OD/1989/NN OMP TRECENTO UNO SPORTS STEERING WHEEL 300mm in BLACK POLYURETHANE', 'country': 'GB', 'primaryCategory': {'categoryId': '40195', 'categoryName': 'Steering Wheels & Boss Kits'}, 'autoPay': 'false', 'galleryURL': 'http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/miOhEO1pDb2cff4pPcZpwIQ/140.jpg', 'shippingInfo': {'shippingType': 'Free', 'shipToLocations': ['AU', 'Americas', 'Europe', 'Asia'], 'shippingServiceCost': {'_currencyId': 'GBP', 'value': '0.0'}}, 'location': 'United Kingdom', 'topRatedListing': 'false', 'viewItemURL': 'http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/OD-1989-NN-OMP-TRECENTO-UNO-SPORTS-STEERING-WHEEL-300mm-BLACK-POLYURETHANE-/322324027874', 'sellingStatus': {'currentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'GBP', 'value': '78.28'}, 'timeLeft': 'P25DT0H21M7S', 'convertedCurrentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'GBP', 'value': '78.28'}, 'sellingState': 'Active'}, 'paymentMethod': 'PayPal', 'isMultiVariationListing': 'false', 'condition': {'conditionId': '1000', 'conditionDisplayName': 'New'}, 'listingInfo': {'listingType': 'FixedPrice', 'gift': 'false', 'bestOfferEnabled': 'false', 'startTime': '2016-11-10T16:13:08.000Z', 'buyItNowAvailable': 'false', 'endTime': '2016-12-10T16:13:08.000Z'}}], '_count': '1'}, 'version': '1.13.0'}
>>> csv_columns = ['itemId','title','subtitle','viewItemURL']
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=csv_columns, extrasaction='ignore')
>>> writer.writeheader()
>>> writer.writerows(response_dict['searchResult']['item'])
>>> print out.getvalue()
itemId,title,subtitle,viewItemURL
322324027874,OD/1989/NN OMP TRECENTO UNO SPORTS STEERING WHEEL 300mm in BLACK POLYURETHANE,100% GENUINE OMP STEERING WHEEL - NOT A CHEAP FAKE COPY,http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/OD-1989-NN-OMP-TRECENTO-UNO-SPORTS-STEERING-WHEEL-300mm-BLACK-POLYURETHANE-/322324027874
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that made things really clear I will give it a go in a minute